# Can someone tell is this transistor or capacitor or what?

Tags: transistors, capacitor

Can someone tell me what is this ? what kind of transistors is this ? and what does it called and i need full info about it, forgive my ignorance,

[image]

Comment: @EugeneSh. I doubt it, they use standard R nomenclature elsewhere... Maybe a fuse though.

Comment: "NF" in the refdes suggests ... non-resettable fuse? noise filter? not a transistor. Measure its resistance, I'd expect pretty close to 0.

Comment: And what type of resistors is this, and what the R stands for ? and from where i can order it, because i need to replace it,

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Trevor You are right. The single uppercase letter seem to be a common marking on fuses.

Comment: @zewOlF: How do you know you need to replace it when you don't know what it is?

Comment: @Transistor This thing is located on a sapphire nitro r9 390 board, i have 3 of this card, one of them has stopped working, and when i tested it on the faulty card it gives different values from the working cards, so i tried to make short on it and the card worked, so thats how i know it needs to be replaced

Comment: L301 (marked 2R2) looks like it might have a problem. Perhaps the current that blew the fuse damaged it?

Comment: It's good you got it working, but bad that you thought a transistor could have only 2 terminals  ... chortle chortle 2410SFV1.25FM/125

Comment: Thanks alot guys but i think i know the reason that blew the fuses, its IOR 3553m something like the transistor i dont know what it is https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1At2hOVXXXXXbaXXXq6xXFXXXk/Free-shipping-5pcs-lot-3553MTRPBF-3553M-laptop-p-new-original.jpg_640x640.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably a (non-resettable) fuse. Unfortunately the letter code indicating the current rating is not standardized and even changes with fuse size within a single manufacturer's product offerings.

See, for example, [this](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_2410sfv_datasheet.pdf.pdf) datasheet.

[image]

Comment: You could make them into tiny alphabet blocks, for mice.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Thank you for your answer, i have another question, if shorted this fuse will that make the card consume more power ? as before the card stopped working it was consuming 290w and after i shorted this fuse it started to heat alot and consumes 450w, so since it is a fuse as i understands it should not affect power consumption

Comment: Sounds like something else has failed causing the high power draw - resulting in a blown fuse. The fuse is a result not a cause of the failure.

Comment: If the fuse blew, it is because something was drawing too much current.  By bridging the fuse, you have allowed whatever it is to continue drawing too much current.  The fuse isn't responsible for that.  It did its job by burning out.  You need to find and fix the problem before replacing the fuse.

Comment: @zewOlF Unless you did something to blow the fuse, it is almost 100% certain that something else is horribly wrong and your PCB needs servicing, preferably by someone with a schematic and ability to board-level troubleshooting. Shorting it may cause additional damage.

Comment: Thanks alot guys but i think i know the reason that blew the fuses, its IOR 3553m something like the transistor i dont know what it is https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1At2hOVXXXXXbaXXXq6xXFXXXk/Free-shipping-5pcs-lot-3553MTRPBF-3553M-laptop-p-new-original.jpg_640x640.jpg

Comment: @zewOlF That's a power stage made by IR (now owned by Infineon), and what you are saying is plausible. Probably P/N [IR3553MTRPBF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir3553.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355cd94ee1767). About $6 in one-off- it won't be particularly easy to replace without the proper equipment.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany , the one i have IOR 3553m c517p ws3h, so First i need to tell you i am not an electrical engineer, i am noob in that, forgive my ignorance,.... so i have some questions i need to know.. first: does this serial c517p ws3h matter? as i understand from the datafile it is just Site/Date/Marking Code and ws3h is Lot Code ? so should i get it with the same data written on it ?... second question: i am located in Egypt and we do not have this kind of things for sale around here, so where can i order it online ? i see its only available on aliexpress which i don't like to order from